# Plugin QGIS Error "QTextEdit.setPlainText(QString): not enough arguments"

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I try to make save as button but i got this error message when try to save file in my directory

```
File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\condition\conditiondialog.py", line 80, in saveAs
    self._save( _filename )
File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\condition\conditiondialog.py", line 68, in _save
    f.write( 'Rekomendasi :' + str(self.ui.textRec1.setPlainText() ) )
TypeError: QTextEdit.setPlainText(QString): not enough arguments
```

this is my code

```
        Smpan = self.ui.btnSave
        QtCore.QObject.connect(Smpan, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.saveAs)       

    def Compare1(self):
        input1 = self.ui.lineInput1.text()
        input2 = self.ui.lineInput2.text()
        compare = ''
        if input1 == input2:
            compare = 'Data dapat digunakam'
        else:
            compare = 'Data tidak cocok'
        self.ui.textRec1.setPlainText(compare)

    def _save(self, simpan):        
        f = open( simpan, 'w' )
        f.write( 'Input 1 :' + str(self.ui.lineInput1.text()) ) 
        f.write( 'Input 2 :' + str(self.ui.lineInput2.text()) )
        f.write( 'Rekomendasi :' + str(self.ui.textRec1.setPlainText()) )       
        f.close()
    def savefile(self):
        if self.simpan:
              self._save( "%s" % self.simpan )
        else:
              self.saveAs()

    def saveAs(self):
            tulis = QtGui.QFileDialog(self).getSaveFileName()
            if tulis !="":
                _filename = "%s" % tulis
                self._save( _filename )
```

Answer (score 1):

Its telling you the problem - you have to pass an argument to setPlainText().

Perhaps you really wanted to use plainText() (to get back 'Data dapat digunakam' or 'Data tidak cocok') though.

*Note that this question doesn't really belong here (because its a general programming issue, not specific to QGIS), but would be appropriate on StackOverflow or similar programming site. Selamat Tahun Baru!*